# How to handle the Session.End event outside Global.asax

Tags: c#, asp.net

Officially the HttpSession event End is handled only in the Global.asax file, but I was wondering if is it there a way, although not officially (eg. Reflection) to handle the event in a different way.

Answer (score 2):

This is not something that can be easily accomplished in an HttpModule, as the Session_OnEnd event may occur outside the scope of a request to the system.  You are probably better off handling this through a custom Session State provider, where your Session management code is what triggers the Session_OnEnd event.

Answer (score 0):

i am not that expert on this matter, but i think you can use HTTPModule, as it allow to have access to all the events pf hte ASPX page, here is a link to nice article on creating HTTP Modules.

http://www.15seconds.com/Issue/020417.htm

hope this helps.